# How to return observable in observable map in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I can really find no words for what I want to do. So I just show my attempt..This is what I tried:

```
register(): Observable<boolean> {

   return this.registerNew().pipe(
     map(userData => {
       return this.updateProfile().pipe(                   (*1)
         map(profileData => {
           return profileData ? true : false;
         }))
     }))
}
```

But of course I get the following error message:

`Type 'Observable<false | Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.`

I am also thinking about using await instead of return in the line which I marked with (*1).

But still I can't get it to work in a nice way.

Comment: [`.flatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/flatMap)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to switch from one observable to another and use the value from the previous there is a `switchMap` operator which can be used like that

```js
register(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.registerNew().pipe(
    switchMap(userData => {
      return this.updateProfile().pipe(
        map(profileData => {
          return profileData ? true : false;
        }))
     }));
}
```

What causes to happen `registerNew`, then it passes resulting value to the `switchMap` returning observable (switchMap has to return an observable to work) and then the result of the inner observable (`updateProfile`) comes to subscriber.

Comment: should not true of false be wrapped like of(true) || of(false)?

Comment: It's `map` not `switchMap`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map values of your observable to another observable, you want to use `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, or `concatMap` (depending on how you want the values of the newly created observable to be emitted).

`await` is not for Observables, only Promises.

Answer (score 1):

You use the [switchMapTo()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmapto.html) operator when you don't need the emitted value, and just want to switch to another observable.

```
register(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.registerNew().pipe(
     switchMapTo(this.updateProfile()),
     map(Boolean)
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `concatMap`.

1. this example calls for the user id first, only when it has returned
2. the second "observable" uses the returned value from the first to
   make the user query

```
this.authenticationService.currentUser.pipe(
    concatMap((principal: Principal) => this.getUser(principal.id))
).subscribe((user: User) => {
    console.log(user); // the user
});
```